# Good CSS framework for beginners?

Tags: css, frameworks

I'm new to CSS but i'm really starting to get it. HTML i know pretty good aswell, and some PHP..

Now i'm looking for a fun CSS Framework to work with, which is easy to pick up for beginners like me and that will make things go a little more fast. :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) is very common, but I would just hand-code everything if you are a beginner, you will know more and benefit from doing it yourself later on. I would definitely check out [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), if you have not already.

Comment: +1 for coding yourself.  Though, to get the basics of how a responsive framework works, I'd suggest looking at Columnal before trying to code your own.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty small system would be Columnal - http://www.columnal.com

Pretty powerful, open to be edited fairly easily, hard to break, overall good.  I would suggest it.

Subscribe to some blog sites, like css-tricks.com and smashingmagazine.com.  Some good content flowing through those places.